# charge pump - failure analysis

Tags: troubleshooting, charge-pump

I have a strange  behavior on a custom [powerstep01](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/powerstep01.pdf) board I designed.

This is the Schematic of the CP / BOOT section:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP1k9t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The values for the capacitors are chosen from the "typical application" section.
[image]

So here is my problem.
I have 2 boards. 1 is 100% working. Another one shows the following behavior of the charge pump.

the device is supposed to be running at 20V to 24V.
When I set STBY to HIGH (get the device out of standby), the charge pump starts running, but at an out of spec. frequency of about 2.6Mhz - 2.7Mhz.
According to the datasheet it should be between 660kHz and 800kHz.
[image]
The voltage swing is from 0.3V to 7.3V - so it's about 7V_PkPK \$7V_{PkPk}\$
This results in about \$6.7V_{PkPk}\$ on the diodes and then finally only about 6.3V added voltage to the power rail on the BOOT pin.
This in turn is sometimes not enough to reach the "Turn On Threshold" and the device remains in ULVO (Flag in the register set).
[image]

During trouble shouting I figured, when I increase the supply voltage to about 28V, suddenly the charge pump stabilizes to 750kHz with \$7.8V_{PkPk}\$. Which results in about 7V added to the power rail on the boot pin. The ULVO is then not triggered and the whole circuit is working perfectly fine.
After it stabilized I can turn it back to 20V-24V and it remains working.

What I have tried (and failed):
reduce and increase the value of C1.
reduce and increase the value of C2.
Change the diodes (same type).
Tripple checked all solder joints / pins.

I'm running out of ideas
What else could be wrong with my charge pump setup?

Comment: Pcb layout is critical for this device. What capacitors are you using? Part numbers/reference required.